# How to view app data on google app engine datastore?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have made an android app which saves user input data in a googele app engine datastore. I want to view the stored entity on google developers console.
How can I do it? On left hand side menu I can see Query menu which takes me to my entity page but no entities are shown, just an ID.
Please advise.

Manish

Comment: If there's anything stored, the Query page of the developers console shows, at the top, a button `Create Entity`, and just below, `KIND` then a dropdown showing the name of a kind of entity and then a `Filters` button -- the entities follow.  Not sure what you mean by "just an ID", perhaps take a screen snapshot, post it somewhere online, and add a link here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If no entities are shown, this means there are no entities. If you see something like

```
id= 595005
```

and nothing else, this means you have an entity with no properties.

You can also try the older version of the [Datastore Viewer](https://appengine.google.com/) (look for the link in the left menu).

Comment: I could actually see all of my entities on older link.Don't know how to do that on newer version?I have another question on datastore. Suppose I plan my entity structure to change, like adding new fields, then how would my older entities be handled?I mean, would query API throw error or would it just populate new fields as null for older entities?

Comment: It will show new properties as "missing". You have to explicitly set a new property to `null` if you need it, for example, for indexing purpose.